# How to insert result to table with "WITH AS" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have `WITH AS` clause in my code

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(Field_1 INT, Field_2 INT)
INSERT @MyTable VALUES
(1,2),
(2,2)

WITH x AS ( SELECT Field_1, Field_2  FROM @MyTable)
SELECT * FROM x
```

How can I insert result of above code to the same table?
I'm tring to insert like:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(Field_1 INT, Field_2 INT)
INSERT @MyTable VALUES
(1,2),
(2,2)
WITH x AS ( SELECT Field_1, Field_2  FROM @MyTable)

INSERT INTO @MyTAble (SELECT * FROM x)
SELECT * FROM @MyTable
```

But it does not work. Management Studio mark `@MyTAbl`e like `Invalid object name @MyTable`
How can I do it? I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Please don't tag both.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using SQL Server 2008. I already edited my post.

Comment: In the future please tag the question with the right version. Also just for clarity SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2 are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you meant this (semi-colons and other little syntax things are important!),

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(Field_1 INT, Field_2 INT);
------------------------------------------------^

INSERT @MyTable VALUES
(1,2),
(2,2);
-----^    

WITH x AS ( SELECT Field_1, Field_2  FROM @MyTable)
------------------------------------------^
INSERT INTO @MyTAble  SELECT * FROM x ;
---------------------^---------------^^

SELECT * FROM @MyTable;
--------------^-------^
```

...but I don't think this will work in MySQL.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. I'm using SQL Server R2.

Comment: Yes, you are right, just a lot of mistakes in my code. Now it works fine! Thanks!